# How to do versioning for assets in a CRA (create-react-app)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I need to add versioning to assets, meaning images and bundled js files. Such that I can set control-cahce headers. Never really touched any aspect of this in web development before, relatively new.

```
"react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
```

But I am unsure of how to do this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I did not realize the assets that wasn't versioned properly was not inside src. It was assets outside the webpack scope. Just moved them from public and use module imports instead to make it work.